# using the not ! operator with punctiation in Microsoft word find

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working in a Word document using a macro trying to identify a string in a wildcard search using the not [!] operator to identify the string only if it has no commas:

So for the string -

```
while at Generic Laboratory, Generic Plant. Your medical...
```

I want it to find it the string only if the comma is not there, which I have been writing like this:

```
(while at)(*[!,]*)(. Your medical)
```

Or

```
(while at)(*)([!,])(*)(. Your medical)
```

This doesn't exclude the string if the comma is there. I've tried using char(44) to ID the comma with no success. Does anyone know a way I can keep the string from being selected if it has any commas in it?

The point is to catch the string only if it is just the statement:
   while at Generic Plant. Your medical...
so I can insert the word the in the replace string like:
\1 the \3\4 etc

Comment: Could you please include an example of the text you're searching, as well as the actual macro code for the search? This will help us with testing - we can copy/paste rather than having to think out and create a repro test. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add information.

Comment: IIR Word uses the standard regex escape character (backslash) for that: `[\!,]`.

Comment: Comintern, I want to find the string only if the comma is NOT there [!,] or [!\,], not if exactly the comma is there [\,] ,right? I tried it the way you wrote it na dint found the string only when it had a comma in it.

Comment: Cindy Meister, I have edited the post to include an example. Please let me know if that helps you give any asistance, or if more is needed. Thanks.

Comment: @LukeLangston To reply to someone, specifically, you need to preced their name with a `@`, otherwise we don't get a notification. The exception is when writing a comment targeted at the person who wrote the contribution (question or answer). So to tell me you've added content you need it; to ask macropod you don't - he'll get that notification.

Comment: thanks @Cindy Meister. Hope this one finds you.

Comment: Yes, the notification worked this time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Find = (while at )([!,]@. Your medical)
Replace = \1the \2
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked! Why doesn't the wildcard * work in that statement like (while at )([!,]*. Your medical) ?

Comment: Also, is there any way to find a string not containing specified words. like in "at the Generic plant and Generic Laboratory" have it only find the string if the "and" is not there? like "at the Generic Plant." ?

Comment: «Why doesn't the wildcard * work in that statement» Because in that construction, [!,] is limited to the first character following the space - the * negates it for everything thereafter. So why the downvote?

Comment: «is there any way to ... have it only find the string if the "and" is not there?» You could use something like Find = (while at )([!a][!n][!d]@. Your medical) but that won't catch those with commas.

Comment: Sorry @macropod, I didn't downvote. I really don't know how that happened. I'll figure out how to change it and get it changed.

Comment: apparently, I didn't accidentally downvote, since it's not showing on my dash. Someone else must have. I tried upvoteing, but it tells me it's recorded, but not displayed, since I don't have 15 reputation points. yet. I'll come back and upvote it once I do. Thanks again for your help.